# Statistical Difference from Zero

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I have a set of data that represents periodic readings. The data shows an upward trend but I need to test for a statistical difference from zero. I believe I should use the t test, two tailed but what should I use for the second set of data? Zeros, the starting value?

```
0.2245
0.243
0.2312
0.1795
0.1923
0.17
0.2025
0.2059
0.2394
0.205
0.2201
0.2261
0.1817
0.2143
0.2126
0.237
0.1984
0.228
0.2292
0.2236
0.2096
0.2258
0.2155
```

Comment: To be more specific I plotted the above data and R and added a trend line geom_smooth(method="lm") which results in an upward trend. I need to find if that upward trend is significantly different from no change.

Answer (score 9):

A t-test would be able to test if the average of all the values is different from 0. There is no second set of data, you want a one-sample t-test. In `R`:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4) #PUT YOUR DATA HERE
t.test(x)
```

would do.

But if you want to test whether the **trend** is different from 0, that's a different question. How to do that would depend on whether the time intervals in your data are equal, whether you want to look at possible seasonality and so on. A simple (but possibly incorrect) method would be:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4) #PUT YOUR DATA HERE
time <- seq(1,length(x))
model1 <- lm(x~time)
```

before that, though, I would make some plots, e.g

```
plot(x~time)
```

and perhaps look at some smoothers.

Comment: But do we also need to show that the data comes from a normal distribution ?

Answer (score 4):

No, don't use 0s, use the [one sample t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#One-sample_t-test) and test whether the mean differs from 0 (it does).
In `R` it goes as follows:

```
x <- c(0.2245, 0.243, 0.2312, 0.1795, 0.1923, 0.17, 0.2025, 0.2059, 
0.2394, 0.205, 0.2201, 0.2261, 0.1817, 0.2143, 0.2126, 0.237, 
0.1984, 0.228, 0.2292, 0.2236, 0.2096, 0.2258, 0.2155)
> t.test(x)

        One Sample t-test

data:  x 
t = 52.3, df = 22, p-value < 0.00000000000000022
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2052 0.2222 
sample estimates:
mean of x 
   0.2137
```

Comment: I agree with Peter Flom that the problem is definitely more difficult than sketched here if you want to know about a trend, then reading times are necessary (or are they equally spaced).